# Deformation when parenting armature and character

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

i'm new to blender and I watched a rather good tutorlial to make an armature and connect it with the character. However, My character all went weird when I made the ctrl+p armatur deform with automatic weight. How can I fix that ? (by the way i'm a noob so i really need clear explanation with shortcuts and all) Thanks ![image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Try adding an armature modifier or use rigify